# Syntax error for the most basic Python code

Tags: python

I have just started learning python and it seems I am getting errors with one line of code

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
  File "hello.py", line 2
    print ‘hello world!’
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

FULL CODE

```
# coding: utf-8
print ‘hello world!’
```

I'm not really sure what could be going wrong in this one simple line

Comment: If this is python3, then `print` needs to be called like a function: `print('hello world!')`. Oh, and it looks like you're using the wrong type of quotes `'`.

Comment: It looks you're using some kind of formatted quote character. You want `'`, not `‘`.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes, to be specific `'` instead of `’`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# coding: utf-8
print 'hello world!'
```

Python accepts either single `'` or double `"` quotes for strings. On special multiline occasions you can use triple quote `'''`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I realized that I had to change the mac defaults....very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 requires parentheses after print:

```
 print('hello world')
```